# looking for a sensor that activates when hit by a certain note

Tags: led, sensor

The reason may seem a bit silly, but anyway: I am trying to turn a violin steampunk. I have never done this before and I'm not the best at engineering, so could someone help? The circuitry doesn't have to be invisible (cables showing etc. are A-okay), but it would be cool if I could find something to light up LEDs when a certain note is played. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams How many  notes can a violin play? Because from the little knownledge I know about violin there is multiple frequency, each string and their mode right? Therefore, it look like more a signal processing problem than simply light up 1 led when being a certain range of frequency.

Comment: @MathieuL: That depends on how many notes "a certain note" is.

Comment: Any instrument has a center fundamental frequency harmonics are centered around. The variations of sound between the instruments are the amount of presence and length those harmonics have. It's still a slight sound processing problem as you'd have to identify the fundamental and ignore the harmonics, since the harmonics can overlap from different fundamentals.

Comment: The violin ranges from G3 to E7. I left it unspecified because I don't really mind which notes will activate the sensor (again, I don't really know much about electronics, don't know if that makes a difference). Ideally, the sensor could activate when playing an open string, so G3, D4, A4 and E5. Is that possible, even with the problem @MathieuL mentioned?

Comment: there's a gizmo that guitar players use to produce MIDI from an ordinary guitar. I forget what it's called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing that comes to mind is a tuner. The one I have has an LED that lights up when the string you're tuning is exactly at the right pitch.
However this is of no use in your situation because it's way too precise and you're stuck to the basic notes. But perhaps modifying such a device could make it work the way you want. There are very cheap ones available on eBay.
http://r.ebay.com/ajjx60